# Too many LDAPConnThreads being created

Tags: java, oracle, ldap, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I've been debugging a WebLogic 10.3.6 stack where the system runs out of threads under load.

Using jstack, I can see that it's creating literally thousands of LDAPConnThread threads over time ... I believe roughly creating one such thread each time a JMS container thread processes a JMS message.

I don't understand how or why these are being created.  I've dug into the WebLogic admin console and can see the LDAP provider in the active security realm ... it appears to be configured to use a connection pool, default size 6.

And yet ... def see the # of threads growing over time with `watch -n 1 -d "ps -eL <pid> | wc -l"` and jstack as it grows indicates the LDAPConnThread- are to blame.

I'm assuming something in my worker processing codepath makes a call to a service that needs LDAP authentication and it's somehow spinning up a new thread rather than using pool.

So I guess my main question is "how can I find what is creating the new threads" other than code-spelunking?

Much thanks!
Daniel